# How to check View size in Teradata

Tags: teradata

In Teradata DB, generally expectation would be to get the data size for a table, but for my task I need to identify size of a View. This view contains joins from 3 different tables and all I could identify is the count of the View - 757747

Should I directly use this count and apply formula to determine it size?. If so what would be formula, is it `sum(currentperm)` I am confused, please advise

Comment: What "size" do you mean, size after exporting to a flat file (which format), perm space to store it as a table, spool space needed to create the answer set? `create table as (select * from view) with data no primary index` will materialize it and then you can query `dbc.TableSizeV`. Or check `dbc.QryLogV` or `dbc.QryLogStepsV` for spool usage.

Comment: @dnoeth yes I was trying to identify flat file size. Your idea of materializing worked out well.